# I want my inherited class to have the same constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

Because my constructor is just `Ent::Ent(string InputID) { ID = InputID; }`.

I want this to be the same for all classes that inherit that class.

Everyone says the constructor is different somehow from other functions of inherited class???

Answer (score 9):

In C++11 you can pull all of the constructors of a parent type into a derived type with [the `using` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int v) : value(v) { }

    int value;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
    B b = B(1);
    std::cout << b.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/y0y2XR).)

This will create a set of *inheriting constructors* in `B` that call the corresponding constructor in `A` to initialize the base object.

You must do this in each derived class, but it beats having to write each constructor you want to "inherit" by hand.

Comment: using "A::A" names A's constructor, which is not allowed yet by all complilers, IIRC.

Comment: @Rob It's allowed beginning in C++11. If a compiler claims to support C++11 and doesn't support this then it's not a conforming compiler.

Comment: @user3391187 No, the 2010 edition doesn't implement this feature at all. :( If you're stuck with this compiler then you have to go the old-school route and implement the derived constructors by hand.